# Dimensions of perturbative parameter in $\varphi^3$ theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, dimensional-analysis, perturbation-theory, interactions

In QFT, $\lambda\varphi^4$ is one of the most studied interactions for the scalar field. The parameter $\lambda$ is adimensional, which makes the perturbative treatment straightforward.

In the case of the interaction $g \phi^3$ (or any interaction where the perturbative parameter has dimensions of energy), how do we apply perturbation theory? $g$ is small with respect to what? The mass of the field? In such a case, what if the field is massless?

Edit: I am considering 3+1 dimensions.

Comment: I think you are going to run into bigger problems than dimensionality in a massless phi-cubed theory. But anyways, you could try to solve this non-perturbatively: $\ddot \phi + 3g\phi^2 = 0$

Answer (score 1):

In QFT we generally fix $\hbar=c=1$ so every dimension can be expressed using one independent dimension, which is generally taken as $[M]$.
$$[M]=[L]^{-1}=[T]^{-1}$$

Actions is defined as ${\mathcal {S}}=\int \mathrm {d} ^{D-1}x\mathrm {d} t{\mathcal {L}}$ and it is dimensionless (here $D$ is the dimension of spacetime)
$$\Rightarrow[\mathcal {L}]=[L]^{-D}=[M]^{D}\Rightarrow[m^2\phi^2]=[M]^{D}\Rightarrow [\phi]=[M]^{\frac{D-2}{2}}$$

Since we add $g \phi^3$ to $\mathcal {L}$ it also has dimensions $[M]^{D}$
$$\Rightarrow [g][\phi^3]=[M]^{D}\Rightarrow [g]=[M]^{D}([M]^{\frac{D-2}{2}})^{-3}=[M]^{\frac{6-D}{2}}$$
For 4D spacetime we get $[g]=[M]^{1}.$

Also, note that since theories whose coupling has negative mass dimensions are nonrenormalizable this $g \phi^3$ is **nonrenormalizable if $D>6$.**

When we say $g$ is small we say with respect to $m^{\frac{6-D}{2}}$.

If you are talking about massless particles it will be a little complicated. For example, **we can't compare the coupling constant of QED which is nothing but the charge of the electron to anything**. If the photon had some charge (that is if it "couples to itself") then we could compare the charge of the electron to the charge of the photon. **But since photon charge is not nonzero we can't compare**.